# Passing an object pointed to by an iterator by reference to a function C++

Tags: c++, iterator, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I though that I understood iterators and addressing etc. but obviously not. See my below code below which is purely an example.

I need to be able to pass by pointer or reference each structure of *mystructs* to *MyFunc()*. The function should be able to update the actual structure that is passed, and not by copy or value.

I receive the compiler error :

`error: cannot convert 'MY_STRUCT' to 'MY_STRUCT*' for argument '1' to 'void MyFunc(MY_STRUCT*)'`

If I just pass the iterator address, this also doesn't work.

What is the correct way to do this. Thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct
{
   int var1;
   int var2;
   std::string name;

}MY_STRUCT;

std::list<MY_STRUCT> mystructs;

void MyFunc(MY_STRUCT*)
{
    // Do something
}


// populate the list with structs etc.. not included here
//.....


for (std::list<MY_STRUCT>::iterator it = mystructs.begin();it != mystructs.end(); ++it)
{
     MyFunc(*it);
}
```

Comment: Off topic but... `it != mystructs.begin()` should probably be `it != mystructs.end()`.

Comment: @G.M. You're right thanks.. correcting it

Answer (score 2):

Passing by reference in C++ is done with:

```
void MyFunc(MY_STRUCT&)
{
    // Do something
}
```

So your call would be correct, what you currently want is to pass the pointer, which you can do with dereferencing the dereferenced iterator (by passing the address of the dereferenced object):

```
void MyFunc(MY_STRUCT*)
{
    // Do something
}


// populate the list with structs etc.. not included here
//.....
int main() {

    for (std::list<MY_STRUCT>::iterator it = mystructs.begin();it != mystructs.begin(); ++it)
    {
         MyFunc(&*it);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or can I just have my function accept a MY_STRUCT& , then pass *it ... will I still get pass by reference then in this case? Thanks

Comment: Yes you are right. If you declare the parameter as `PARAM&` it is "autoamtically" passed as reference in C++. In the function call you can't see, if is passed by value or reference directly, which I dislike a little bit in the C++ syntax

Answer (score 0):

Your function requires a pointer, use `&` to get the address of something.

```
MyFunc(&*it);
```

`*it` returns a reference to the `MY_STRUCT` object, you need to use `&` to convert that reference to a pointer. This is normal, the fact that you are using iterators makes no difference at all.

The alternative (maybe better in C++) would be to convert your `MyFunc` function to take a reference instead of a pointer.